# How to call async function with .onChange in SwiftUI?

Tags: asynchronous, swiftui, async-await, task, onchange

In SwiftUI, I am trying to call an async function(which is for loading images that is picked by ImagePicker) by using .onChange. I got "'async' call in a function that does not support concurrency" error. If I make function sync and remove "Task {@MainActor in" section, then it runs but I get some purple errors during loading images which I do not want.

Is it possible to use .onChange to call async function?

```
func loadImage() async {
    Task { @MainActor in
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else {
            loadingState = .failed
            return
        }
        jpegData = inputImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)!
        image = Image(uiImage: inputImage)
        loadingState = .loaded
    }
}
```

I try to call the function as below;

```
.onChange (of: addPersonViewModel.inputImage, perform: { _ in addPersonViewModel.loadImage() })
```

If I make function sync and remove "Task {@MainActor in" section, then it runs but I get some purple errors during loading images which I do not want.

Comment: Hi @Gorkem, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add sample code that demonstrates the problem, _that can be run by someone trying to solve it_. In SwiftUI, ideally a `struct ContentView` that can be pasted into Xcode. Please read [mcve]

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
.onChange (of: addPersonViewModel.inputImage, perform: { _ in addPersonViewModel.loadImage() })
```

Use

```
.task(id:addPersonViewModel.inputImage){
 await addPersonViewModel.loadImage() }
```

You will have to make a slight modification to your function

```
func loadImage() async {

    guard let inputImage = inputImage else {
        loadingState = .failed
        return
    }
    jpegData = inputImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)!
    image = Image(uiImage: inputImage)
    loadingState = .loaded

}
```

That floating `Task` inside a function is not a good practice.

Comment: I tried and get "Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates." purple error.

Comment: @GorkemTuran put “@MainActor” on the ViewModel (above the class declaration). It’s purpose is to update the view so it should always be wrapped.

Comment: `task(id:)` is good, now just remove the view model

Comment: @malhal we have discussed the whole View Model thing before, I don't mind if people use it. Have you tried coding something with `strict` concurrency?, it will become nearly impossible to code without an additional `class` or `struct` if the warnings that are appearing now stay. SwiftUi wrappers like `State` and `Binding` make SwiftUI Views non-Sendable it is quite a disaster.

Comment: @GorkemTuran if I answered your question do you mind clicking on the green checkmark to accept the answer?